# How to Determine Which C# Settings File Is Being Used

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, settings.settings

The Settings.settings  file that's part of my C# application has the following `User` entry. It is called selected_device_idx; is an `int`; and its value is set to -1.

Yet, during startup, when I fetch this value, it is set to another value, 5.

I am using this to fetch the value

`int temp_selected_device_idx = (int)Properties.Settings.Default["selected_device_idx"];`

How can I determine where the origin of this entry?

Comment: You could search for the string "selected_device_index" in all of your project's source files. Also, I'll admit it's been a while since I worked with the settings stuff, but shouldn't you be able to write `int temp_selected_device_idx = Properties.Settings.Default.selected_device_idx;`?

Comment: Well, if 5 isn't the default value then it comes from a user.config file.  It is hard to find back because it is stored in a AppData directory with a strange name.  If you can't find it then SysInternals' Process Monitor can show you.  Or just write back whatever value you want and Save() it.

Comment: Please answer this with what you've written here along with the user file is stored as user.config under the user's AppData\Local\<application_name> directory.

Comment: You can also answer it and just refer to Hans' comment

Answer (score 0):

I am reposting @HansPassant 's comment as the answer. sz Now, I have to find out why the settings are not holding on a non-development workstation, where I am installing this application.

Hans, Thanks for the comment.

***Well, if 5 isn't the default value then it comes from a user.config file. It is hard to find back because it is stored in a AppData directory with a strange name. If you can't find it then SysInternals' Process Monitor can show you. Or just write back whatever value you want and Save() it. –  Hans Passant yesterday***

Comment: I suggest using Process Monitor on the non-development PC to find out what files are being accessed by your program. Does it show any problems, like "Access denied"?